# Implementing Error description with own string

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'd like to implement an error description which uses one of the error's parameters, but I can't find a way to return a description which doesn't disappear.

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
pub struct MissingParamError {
    name: Box<String>
}

impl Error for MissingParamError {
    fn description(&self) -> &str {
        &format!("Missing parameter {}", self.name)
    }
}
```

This of course causes an error due to the generated description going out of scope.

Is there any workaround for this apart from:

- adding `MissingParamError::new` which will pre-render full description
- adding an `Option<String>` which would render the description on demand and keep it around

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No; the method signature simply does not allow you to dynamically construct the string.  Also, because it uses `&self` (*i.e.* an immutable pointer), you can't use your second workaround.

Since all types that implement `Error` must *also* implement [`Display`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html) (whose whole purpose is to format a value for display to the user), *that* would be the appropriate place to generate a non-trivial message.

Or as you suggested, if you're feeling lazy, do it in `MissingParamError::new`.

---

<s>Actually, you *can* use the second workaround if you switch to `RefCell<Option<String>>` in order to get interior mutability, but that's a bit overkill.</s>

Actually actually, you can't, since you can't get a long-lived borrow from a `RefCell` (thanks, @bluss).

Comment: We should add, this is intentional: description is for a *cheap* error description, use `Display` trait for an allocated/formatted error text. (You can't get a long lived borrow out of the RefCell either)

Comment: Eagerly constructing a string in `new` is hardly *lazy*… 

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: It's *very* lazy, after all, to do it lazily would require more effort.  (Can't see that last character, no idea what tone you were going for)

Comment: You are mixing the lazy programming term with the English lazy. The former means to wait to do something until the last second (on demand) and usually cache the result. The latter is the amount of effort the human puts into the code. A non-lazy human can create lazily-evaluated code. ^_^